# to test the save statement in the views.py

Tags: python, django

I designed a test initialy, because the idea is to apply TDD, the test should test that a register is saved and this can be executed correctly(the save()), but the test should fail, because obviously, the code in the views module doesn't exist to save, somebody that help me to complete the test adequately to test the save.

This is the test file:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.conf import settings##
from django.utils.importlib import import_module##
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from key_process_indicator_bsc.views.views_process_indicator import *
from key_process_indicator_bsc.models import *


class ProcessIndicatorTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data_key_process_indicator_bsc.json']

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_pi_insert_basic(self):
        #user = auth_user.objects.get(username="lruedc")
        indicator_type = IndicatorType.objects.get(name="eficacia")
        unite_measure = UniteMeasure.objects.get(name="horas")
        periodicity_indicator = PeriodicityIndicator.objects.get(pk = 1)
        indicator_process = IndicatorProcess.objects.get(pk = 1)
        frecuency = Frecuency.objects.get(detail="semanal")
        formula = Formula.objects.get(detail = "2ab") 

        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = 'POST'
        request.POST['name'] = "Cumplimiento del margen EBITDA"
        request.POST['goal'] = "100"
        request.POST['weight'] = "50"
        request.POST['minimum_range'] = 20
        request.POST['hight_range'] = 40
        request.POST['acountable'] = 1
        request.POST['responsible'] = 1
        request.POST['indicator_type'] = indicator_type.id
        request.POST['unite_measure'] = unite_measure.id
        request.POST['formula'] = formula.id
        request.POST['process'] = indicator_process.process
        request.POST['indicator_process_type'] = indicator_process.indicator_process_type
        request.POST['indicator_process'] = indicator_process.id
        request.POST['frecuency'] = frecuency.id
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        ProcessIndicatorInsert.as_view()(request)
```

This is the views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
#from ..forms import LoginForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class ProcessIndicatorInsert(View):

    template_name = 'key_process_indicator_bsc/index.html'
    def post(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
        })
```

and to run the test, i can see the next:

```
.....................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 21 tests in 0.694s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
(key_process_indicator_bsc_local) root@leidyj-VirtualBox:/home/leidyj/key_process_indicator_bsc_repository/key_process_indicator_bsc#
```

how you can see, the test do not fail and this should, how do i complete the test?.

thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You've got a whole bunch of setup code there, but no actual assertions, so there is nothing to fail.

Comment: it is true, but i don know how to update the test...

Comment: Obviously if your view is supposed to update your db, you have to test that the db has been updated appropriately after the view has been called.

Comment: ok, this i undestand, but i don't know how, you can help me?

Comment: Your view does not interact with the database. You need `django.views.generic.edit.CreateView` to add an item to the database.

Comment: i need to improve the test, and this way continue the codification in views, to continue, the test should fail, the test don´t fail